# Set focus on input field for wrong values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, input, focus

I have a HTML as this:

```
<div id="div1">
  <input name="inText" type="text" id="input1" />
  <input name="inText" type="text" id="input2" />
</div>
```

I want to force the user to enter only text beginning with "a", so I use this jQuery script:

```
$("#div1 input").blur(function (){
    var re = /^a/;
    if ( $(this).val() != "" && ! re.test($(this).val()) ) {
        alert('The text must begin with "a"');
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

However, I do not manage to bring the focus/selection back to the wrong input. If you use the TAB key or click on the next input then the cursor always go there but does not go back.

I also tried this, but no success either:

```
var currentInput;

$("#div1 input").focusout(function (){
    var re = /^a/;
    if ( $(this).val() != "" && ! re.test($(this).val()) ) {
        alert('The text must start with "a"');
        currentInput.focus();
        currentInput.select();
    }
});

$("#div1 input").focusin(function (){
    currentInput = $(this);
});
```

Event `change` is also not working as desired. Any ideas to solve this problem?

After additional test it seems that it works as expected in MS Internet-Explorer but not with Firefox (version 43). Any ideas to make in working in Firefox and major other browsers?

Comment: Your first example works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/f0bxpm7e/. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I tried. When you enter for example "x" at `input1` and hit TAB key you get the alert message (as expected) but after click on "Ok" the cursor is placed at `input2`. I like the focus on the wrong text "x". I tested with Firefox 43.

Comment: When I try, in Chrome, entering 'x' and then tabbing generates the alert and then the input that was left (the one in which 'x' was entered) is re-focused.